# Swap values of two IORefs

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, reference, swap

I need this functionality:

```
x <- newIORef "x"
y <- newIORef "y"
swapIORefs x y
readIORef x -- Outputs "y"
readIORef y -- Outputs "x"
```

My best attempt is:

```
swapIORefs :: IORef a -> IORef a -> IO ()
swapIORefs x y = do let xvalue = readIORef x
                    let yvalue = readIORef y
                    writeIORef x yvalue
                    writeIORef y xvalue
```

Compiler gives me:

```
    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      let yvalue = readIORef y writeIORef x yvalue writeIORef y xvalue
   |
51 |                     let yvalue = readIORef y
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be working:

```
swapIORefs :: IORef a -> IORef a -> IO ()
swapIORefs x y = do xvalue <- readIORef x
                    yvalue <- readIORef y
                    writeIORef x yvalue
                    writeIORef y xvalue
```

`readIORef` has the type `IORef a -> IO a`, whereas `writeIORef` has the type `IORef a -> a -> IO ()`, so in order to write a value, you need to 'get it out of' `IO`, which you can do with a `<-` binding.

The `let` binding in the OP would bind `xvalue` to an `IO a`, and that doesn't typecheck with `writeIORef`.

GHCi:

```
ghci> x <- newIORef "x"
ghci> y <- newIORef "y"
ghci> swapIORefs x y
ghci> readIORef x
"y"
ghci> readIORef y
"x"
```

Comment: This is the important semantic fix, but note that the error message also indicates another way the code in the question is broken. It thinks the `let` is the end of the `do` block, so the indentation must be wrong as well. And indeed if we look at the question source, we see tabs and spaces mixed incorrectly. Both fixes must be applied, not just replacing `let` with `<-`.

Answer (score 0):

slightly shorter, although only syntactically would be:

```
swapIORefs :: IORef a -> IORef a -> IO ()
swapIORefs x y = (readIORef x <* (readIORef y >>= writeIORef x)) >>= writeIORef y
```

This is equivalent to @MarkSeemanns's code, but uses some functions like `>>=` and `<*` to implicitly pass the values to the next refecence.

Comment: This is an exercise. I can’t use such funky words as >>=

Comment: @coderodde: well the funny thing is that `do` blocks are just syntactical sugar to work with `>>=`, so essentially `do` is defined in terms of `>>=`, not the opposite way.

Comment: The actual problem with this solution is that it's totally cryptic. A more reasonable point-free version would be `writeIORef x *** writeIORef y <<< readIORef y &&& readIORef x`, using Kleisli arrows... except actually making that work requires a ludicrous amount of wrapping and dummy-applying: `runKleisli (Kleisli (writeIORef x) *** Kleisli (writeIORef y) <<< Kleisli (const $ readIORef y) &&& Kleisli (const $ readIORef x)) ((),()) >> return ()`.